# How to communicate with a serial io device

Tags: python, serial-port, pyserial

I am trying to communicate with a serial io device through python. The example code is:

```py
import serial
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0')
```

My question is how do you get the `/dev/tyyUSB0` equivalent for my device? If I try changing it I just get the error 'The system cannot find the path specified'. How do I get the correct path?

Comment: You need to get your operating system to list the serial ports on your device.

Comment: Do you happen to know how to do that on windows 11? All of the tutorials I have found say to look for ports in device manager but that's not there for me.

Comment: The code example you show is probably intended only for Linux, specifically a serial terminal using a USB-to-serial (either RS-232 or TTL or even RS-485) adapter. If you're using Windows, then add that to the tags. "*... but that's not there for me*" -- A negative summary isn't helpful because it's ambiguous; the list of things "*not there*" is infinite. How do you know that there's any "serial device" attached?